# Is XFCE dead or still under development?

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, xubuntu

The [XFCE website](https://xfce.org/) seems to be alive, and distros like Xubuntu still use it. But [XFCE hasn't been updated since 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_Window_System_desktop_environments#Overview). Is the project dead?

Comment: Do not mix up the news update on the website with actual changes in the projects. Check https://www.xfce.org/projects and you'll see many updates from this November.

Comment: The roadmap https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/wiki/Roadmap for LXQT hasn't updated since June '16, at the same time the current LXQT version 0.90 was released. So, LXQT isn't that much fresher than XFCE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer to this Question could change over time and contains a matter of opinion ("should we stop using it?")

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There hasn’t been a full release of Xfce for a while, but the project is still alive. The [git repositories](https://git.xfce.org/) are very active, and a number of projects inside Xfce have had releases since Xfce 4.12: Thunar, the file manager, in October 2018, Ristretto, the picture viewer, in August 2018, etc.

Comment: Basically, the current development push is trying to get everything to work properly with GTK+ 3.  I expect there'll be a full release (as opposed to the current piecemeal releases) once that happens.